# how to encrypt integer and date time data type in postgresql using pgcrypto

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here is my code to encrypt the column:

```
UPDATE users 
SET  (userid, modifieddate) = 
(
    PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('0', 'AES_KEY'),
    PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('2018-06-19 08:40:23', 'AES_KEY')
) 
WHERE id='3';
```

but its throwing error:

> column "userid" is of type integer but expression is of type byte

Answer (score 1):

Your table columns `users.userid` and `users.modifieddate` should be type `BYTEA`, because `pgcrypto` module generates encrypted result with `BYTEA` type.

Comment: i cannot alter my table data types

Comment: @adams I am facing a similar issue, did you find a solution such that you can encrypt numeric data and persist the datatype as well?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot encrypt only one user's id and put rest of it as it is , if you want to achieve that you need to alter table as mention by @C.C. Hsu , i.e. to converting data type of userid , modifieddate into bytea or text which is capable of storing both encrypted data and your normal data.

```
alter table users alter column userid type bytea using PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT(userid::text, 'AES_KEY');
alter table users alter column modifieddate type bytea using PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT(modifieddate::text, 'AES_KEY');
```